# How to get xterm on RHEL6 and CentOS6 stock installs?

Tags: installation, terminal, centos, xterm, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have a library of virtual machines on which I am running product testing, and I am encountering an issue with `xterm` not being found.

Originally I thought `xterm` was a basic terminal installed across all Linux distros. I need to get xterm on these systems in the simplest way possible, as the procedure might end up in a user manual.

Is there a command I can enter into the terminal to get this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ yum provides "*bin/xterm"
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, fastestmirror, presto, refresh-packagekit
xterm-253-1.el6.x86_64 : Terminal emulator for the X Window System
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/xterm
```

So do `yum install xterm`

Comment: THANKS! worked like a charm in centOS but when working with Red Hat Enterprise 6 I got the following :          

'loaded plugins: refresh-package-kit, rhnplugin'
'This system is not registered with RHN.'
'RHN support disabled.'
'setting up install process'
'No package xterm available'
'Error : Nothing to do'

I didn't see an RHM plugin loaded into Red Hat any ideas?

Comment: If you have Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 installed, you should have a license to access RHN with it. If you don't have a license to access RHN, you will find it relatively difficult to access Red Hat's RPMs.

Comment: I was afraid of that; perhaps there is an online installer I could download; I will continue the search! Thanks! Your way helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Mount the install RHEL DVD:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/RHEL
mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/RHEL
```

Or if you just have the ISO, you can use that instead:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/RHEL
mount -o loop /path/to/RHEL.iso /mnt/RHEL
```

Now make a Yum repository which uses the DVD as a repository.

Create a file [/etc/yum.repos.d/rhel-dvd.repo] with contents:

```
[rhel-dvd]
name=Red Hat Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch - DVD
baseurl=file:///mnt/RHEL/Server/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

You should now be able to clean the yum cache, and install the 32-bit C library:

```
yum clean all

yum install xterm
```

Hope it helps!!!